# How to change the site language in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

I have developed website in codeigniter and now i want it to be multi-language.

I have followed a tutorial working with hooks. Here is my hook.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor']=array(
                                   'class'=>'LanguageLoader',
                                   'function'=>'initialize',
                                   'filename'=>'LanguageLoader.php',
                                   'filepath'=>'hooks'
                                   );
```

and I have created a class and placed it inside the hooks folder.

```
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

   function switchLanguage($language="")
   {
       $language=($language!="") ? $language:"english"; 
       $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang',$language);
       redirect(base_url());
   }
}
```

and here is another file which is also placed inside the hooks folder

```
class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize()
    {
        $CI=&get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('language');
        $site_lang=$CI->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if($site_lang)
        {
            $CI->lang->load('dari','dari');
        }
        else
        {
            $CI->lang->load('english','english');
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my view file.

```
<a href='<?=site_url('LangSwitcher/switchLanguage/english')?>'>English</a>
```

and it says that "The requested page was not found ". Can any body find it what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is called `LangSwitch` but in your url, you generate "LangSwitch **er**" in `site_url(...)`. If you don't have routes set up for this then it's probably a typo there.

Also, the `if($site_lang)` condition looks wrong in `LanguageLoader`. Maybe you wanted `if ($site_lang == "dari")` and `elseif`s to other supported languages or a `switch()`

Comment: you are right (I typed the question words wrong). I followed the above solution but yet it says that the file was not found. I guess the file placement is a problem. I have placed my LanguageLoader.php and LangSwitch.php in application/hooks/ folder.

Comment: The controller (`LangSwitch`) sould go under the `application/controllers/` folder. Lowercasing the filename shouldn't hurt too.

Comment: That actually worked man. Thanks for the help. One thing more. Is that possible to be on the same page (after the other language button is clicked)?

Comment: You could pass the current uri to the `LangSwitch` controller and use that in the redirect after setting the lang in the session. Something like `<?=site_url('...').'?back='.rawurlencode(uri_string())?> ` and `redirect(site_url($this->input->get('back')));` Might need to load the ur helper.

Comment: yes that is good option. Using GET method is thought to be risky. At this point, I don't think there is any point of hack or vulnerabilities etc. am I right ?

Comment: Someone could use the lang switching redirect to create links that would send them somewjere inside your site, but could simply create the url where the redirect would send them anyawys. Just don't make anything destructive triggerable by GET requests, which is a good idea anyways assisted with csrf. This solution does not make you more exposed to that i think.